# Returning filename and number of pages for each pdf document in a directory

Tags: xargs

CONTEXT: Catalina MacOS:   A set of .pdf files is in a directory.  Some of the filenames have spaces (problematic with xargs.

From the command line: the goal is to return for each .pdf file, the filename and the number of pages.

This snippet returns a list filenames that could be pipelined into [xargs](https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/):

```
find . -type f -name  '*.pdf'
```

These this snippet returns the number of pages:

```
pdfinfo foo.pdf | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}' 


pdftk foo.pdf dump_data | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}'
```

How can the snippets be used with xargs to only process .pdf files that may have spaces in their filenames?

Failed:

```
 find . -name '*.pdf' | xargs pdfinfo |
```

Snippet prints filename (though unable to handle names with spaces) and does not print page number on the same line as filename:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %;  pdfinfo % | grep Pages'
```

Answer (score 2):

> Some of the filenames have spaces (problematic with xargs.

You just need to use the `-print0` option for `find`, and the `-0` option for `xargs`. They should really advertise these very much at the top of their man pages!

```
find -iname '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

just works. These options tell `find` to separate found filenames with a zero byte instead of a newline character. Unlike spaces, newlines, colons, …, zero bytes are *not* allowed within file names, so this is a safe way to separate file names. `-0` tells `xargs` to expect zero bytes as dividers (and nothing else).

However, this is OS X, you got good shells going probably; so, no need for `find` at all.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/zsh -

for pdffile in **/*.pdf(N-.) ; do
   print -r -- "${pdffile}" # This is already problematic again. Your file names
                            # might contain newlines, spaces etc, so no easy way
                            # to tell where file name ends and page count starts
   pdfinfo -- "${pdffile}" | grep Pages | awk '{print $2}'
done
```

Note the **double** quotation marks `"` where you tried to use `'`: Your code cannot work, because `'`-encased string doesn't undergo variable expansion, so the string is passed as-is (including the dollar sign and variable name) to the program being called. Which is what you want for the `awk` argument, because you need to pass `$`, but not where you actually want to expand the content of your variable.

Note that fuzzy drawing's answer is right, you can absorb the grep into the `awk` call. You should also make sure the regex is as precise as possible.

Let's also fix the "file names can contain spaces and newlines and numbers, so in my output I won't be able to tell where file names start and end" issue, by ourselves generating 0-delimited output:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/zsh

for pdffile in **/*.pdf(N-.) ; do
   pages=$(pdfinfo -- "${pdffile}" | awk '/^Pages:/{print $2}')
   printf '%s\0\%d\0' "${pdffile}" "${pages}"
done
```

(you could still have problems with PDF files whose *Creator* or *Producer* contains `<newline>Pages:`, but at least, by using that strict regex above, we've minimised the risk).

Comment: No need for `xargs` and the `-print0`/`-0` GNU extensions. You can use the standard `find ... -exec cmd {} +` syntax here.

Comment: I forget that these are GNU extensions!

Comment: Note though that although they (like `-iname`) started as GNU extensions, they are supported by many more implementations including those of most if not all BSDs including macos. They're still not standard though and not many non-GNU text utilities can deal with nul-delimited records or lines that contain nuls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find`'s `-exec` command to run `pdfinfo` then pipe the result to `awk` which can do pattern-matching on its own without requiring `grep` as an intermediate step:

`find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec pdfinfo '{}' \; | awk '/Pages/ {print $2}'`

Of course that only gives the number of pages and I now see that for each file you want both the **filename** *and* total pages. I don't think `xargs` will help here, but a `while` loop will do the job:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' | while read -r f; do
    p=$(pdfinfo "$f" | awk '/Pages/ {print $2}')
    printf '%s\n' "$f $p"
done
```

Comment: be careful, file names can also contain newlines.

Comment: @MarcusMüller OP mentioned spaces only so I didn't think newlines were a concern.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to go down a directory tree, this `for` loop might do:

```
for FN in *pdf; do pdfinfo "$FN" | awk '/^Pages/ {print ARGV[2], $2; exit}' - "$FN"; done
```

Comment: Any comments / explanation would be helpful to the novice.

Answer (score 1):

With `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -r -ext pdf -q -p '$PageCount $Directory/$Filename' .
```

`-r` (for recursive) in combination with `-ext pdf` would do something similar to `find . -name '*.pdf'`.

That's good for display.

For a post-processable output, like in a shell loop, you'd rather want to use some NUL-delimited output format:

```
exiftool -r -ext pdf -q -if 'print "$PageCount/$Directory/$Filename\0";0' . |
  while IFS=/ read -rd '' page file; do
    something with "$page" and "$file"
  done
```

(assuming `zsh` or `bash -O lastpipe`)

Or some of the serialisation formats it supports such as json, xml or php¹:

```
$ exiftool -r -ext pdf -q -j -PageCount .
[{
  "SourceFile": "./a.pdf",
  "PageCount": 4
},
{
  "SourceFile": "./a\nb.pdf",
  "PageCount": 4
}]
```

```
$ exiftool -r -ext pdf -q -X -PageCount .
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>

<rdf:Description rdf:about='./a.pdf'
  xmlns:et='http://ns.exiftool.ca/1.0/' et:toolkit='Image::ExifTool 11.88'
  xmlns:PDF='http://ns.exiftool.ca/PDF/PDF/1.0/'>
 <PDF:PageCount>4</PDF:PageCount>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about='./a
b.pdf'
  xmlns:et='http://ns.exiftool.ca/1.0/' et:toolkit='Image::ExifTool 11.88'
  xmlns:PDF='http://ns.exiftool.ca/PDF/PDF/1.0/'>
 <PDF:PageCount>4</PDF:PageCount>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```
exiftool -r -ext pdf -q -php -PageCount .
Array(Array(
  "SourceFile" => "./a.pdf",
  "PageCount" => 4
),
Array(
  "SourceFile" => "./a\nb.pdf",
  "PageCount" => 4
));
```

(here with a filename containing a newline character as example).

---

<sup>¹ beware however that the JSON and XML ones only work for filenames made of text properly encoded in UTF-8, a limitation of those formats.</sup>